# KSH Script using SQLPlus will not commit

Tags: bash, oracle, sqlplus, ksh

```
function SQL_Command   
    {
    result=`sqlplus -s /nolog <<!EOF
    connect ********
    whenever sqlerror exit failure
    set pagesize 0
    set feedback off
    $1 
    $2
    exit 0
    !EOF`
    }
```

So I have this function (above) and a few lines of codes beneath which are mostly inserts and updates, but anyhow they are not committed after execution.

I tried to add `commit;` but still it will not like literally be committed :c

function is used like this: `SQL_Command "update ...." "commit;"`
well at least that's what I've tried so far... anyone got any ideas :?

Thanks in advance!

brgds

Comment: Do you have that exact indentation? `!EOF` **must** be the only characters on the line ending the heredoc.

Comment: What do you mean exactly :?

Answer (score 0):

I mean this: the heredoc terminator must not have any leading or trailing whitespace or any other characters*

```
function SQL_Command   
    {
    result=$(sqlplus -s /nolog <<!EOF
    connect ********
    whenever sqlerror exit failure
    set pagesize 0
    set feedback off
    $1 
    $2
    exit 0
!EOF
    ) 
    }
```

*with one exception that you can read about in the bash manual.